# glmnet compilation with C++11

Tags: r, compilation, glmnet

I am working on an old RHEL 7.9 server that only has GCC 4.8.5 which only supports up to C++11. Is there an older version of glmnet that can compile with this compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glmnet 4.1-2 seems to be the latest version that compiles with gcc gnu99 instead of C++14.

Install from source at https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/glmnet/glmnet_4.1-2.tar.gz